# <li> elements (text and bulletpoints) are white

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, wordpress-theming, html-lists

Context: Wordpress 4.3 running the Gonzo theme by Ollie McCarthy.

So I've been trying to work my through through a problem on our current production website and I can't quite figure out what's going on.

Pretty much all `<li>`s are appearing white by default. As an example, try and find the telephone numbers for a random entry on the page (or SELECT ALL) **http://outoftheblue.org.uk/artist-directory**

By inspecting the "hidden" element, it tells me that this is caused by the following function

```
body {
    color: white;
}
```

I can't figure out where this is inherited from. Our prebuilt theme has a style_reset.css which defines anything `<ul>` as #222 (black). No white present. Our main_css is giving me no clues either. I've even tried searching the above string in the whole directory using Notepad++ but to no avail.

Has anyone ever had this problem before or knows of a plugin that may be causing this?

Comment: in style_reset.css try body color:#222!important;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ln 2226 has a style for it and since it's the last matching tag it overrides the ones from your reset as they are the same specificity.

If you add

```
body a, body li, body span {
    color: #222;
}
```

into the reset css, or somewhere else in the page, that should do the trick as it would than have more specificity and therefore take precedence.

Comment: Brilliant, that done the trick. For reference of future users, this also changed the colour of the <h3> text on the sidebar (the white text in the mustard yellow frame) to black. I separated this by simply adding "color:#fff" to the style_main. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's in a footer widget. The one with the text

> Out of the Blue Arts & Education Trust 
>   36 Dalmeny Street, Edinburgh EH6 8RG 
>  0131 555 7100
>
> Scottish Charity SC 022812
>  Company registration number –
>   SC235075
>  Registered in Scotland
>  Limited by Guarantee

I would modify that widget so the `<head>` and `<style>` declarations are gone.

Comment: Good call, thank you. You're absolutely right as adding a main rule on style_reset.css also affected the footer and changed some custom text there black.